# How to make a star-shaped polygon with some given points

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

The problem is about 2D-space.
Each closed curve like $P$, divides the plane into $3$ parts :  $P_0$, which is the area inside the curve, $P^c$, which is the area outside the curve, and $P$ itself. ( Jordan Curve Theorem )

Here, when we speak about a polygon, we mean not just the curve $P$, but also $P_0$.

$\forall x,y \in P\cup P_0$, $x$ can see $y$ clearly iff $\overline {xy} \cap P^c = \emptyset \space \land \overline {xy}\cap P\subset\{x,y\}$

For a polygon like $P$, $Kernel(P)$ is a subset of $P_0$ like $S$ such that :
$\forall s \in S \space \forall p \in P\space\space s$ can see $p$ clearly.

A polygon like $P$ is a star-shaped polygon iff $Kernel(P)\neq \emptyset$

The question :
Assume that $n$ points on the plane are given.  Provide an algorithm for making a star-shaped polygon in which these points are vertices.

Note :  The problem is so easy if the points have a good distance. But i have no idea to solve the problem in general form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A point is connected next to next point.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your definition. If $x$ and $y$ belong to the same side of the polygon, then they cannot see clearly each other, because $\overline{xy}\cap P\not\subset\{x,y\}$. So every polygon would have an empty kernel. What am I missing?

Comment: @Aretino My mistake was that Kernel is not a subset of $P$ but a subset of $P_0$. Excuse me :) i fixed it :)

Comment: OK, but then you should also modify your first definition as $\forall x, y\in P\cup P_0\ \ldots$

Comment: @Aretino yes :) thank you :)